# What is the differance between RUDP and TCP?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

While browsing about RUDP in Wikipedia, I got the following definition

In order to gain ensure quality, it extends UDP by adding the following additional features:
1.Acknowledgment of received packets
2.Windowing and flow control
3.Retransmission of lost packets
4.Overbuffering (Faster than real-time streaming)

THis is what the TCP also does. Now what is the big difference between the two when these features are implemented to UDP.

I am a newbie to networking, Please explain.

Answer (score 4):

TCP establishes persistent connections between 2 endpoints before starting the communication flow.
RUDP doesn't as it provides its services on top of UDP.  From [draft](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-sigtran-reliable-udp-00.txt)

> RUDP is layered on the UDP/IP Protocols and provides reliable in-order
>   delivery (up to a maximum number of retransmissions) for virtual
>   connections

Comment: Don't forget that UDP is message-based while TCP is stream based